# How do I keep validation rules inside of entity while using a view model inside controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

So I've got an entity in my `Models` directory:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(2000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to expose it to views using a viewModel:

```
public class BaseEventViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class EventCreateViewModel : BaseEventViewModel
{

}
```

My reasoning behind this is that I want all the data validation to be done on the entity, and all the presentation stuff (such as rendering a text area) to be done on the view model. Then I can use however many view models I want to represent my entity, while maintaining data integrity.

So I changed my controller to use the new view model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EventCreateViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Events.Add(new Event
            {
                Name = viewModel.Name,
                Description = viewModel.Description
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

However none of the entity validation gets done and I'm able to submit a blank form which raises a `DbEntityValidationException` exception.

Presumably this is because `ModelState.IsValid` is working on the view model, not the entity that the view model represents. How can I catch these validation errors?

Answer (score 5):

I actually found the answer after being prodded in the right direction. If I add this annotation to my view model, it will inherit all of the annotations applied to the properties on my entity:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Event))]
public class BaseEventViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I submit a blank form I get shown the validation errors as normal.

This does come with the caveat of having to redefine every property again inside my view model, which kind of defeats the point of a view model only holding the properties you require, however it works for my case.

Comment: `This does come with the caveat of having to redefine every property again inside my view model` You could put an `Event` object in your view model. That would solve both your problems.

Comment: @Shoe and it will trigger some terrible exceptions for example with ORM lazy loading

Comment: @fex Sure, but you can always do a lookup for a fresh entity based on the id passed. Really a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

Model is all that is passed through action method parameters. Sorry - the only way to achieve that is to add data annotations also in `ViewModels`.

EDIT: It could be appended on runtime with reflection (so changes in `Entity` validation could be automatically "seen" on `ViewModels`) - however that's a lot of work. You would have to inherit from `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`, get all attributes from appropiate `Entity` class properties and add them to viewmodels. I think the best way is to write unit tests for `Entity` and `Viewmodels` validation rules (are same attributes appended to fields in `Entity` and `ViewModel`) - to avoid different validators bugs.

Second good way (and the fastest one) to resolve this kind of problem is to use `AOP` framework like `PostSharp`. Create aspect like: `EntityNameValidatorAspect` (to add data annotations for property with proper attributes values). Then you would add this aspect (`[EntityNameValidatorAspect]`) before name property in `Entity` and `Viewmodel` and so on. That's an analogy of refactoring repeated code to method - you just "refactor" few common attributes into one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your validation rules should be on the view model. The job you're doing is validation user input, and that is what you're using to receive the input.

You could have a separate validation step that is done on the entity prior to being written to the database. In that case, you would use a separate validation mechanism to handle the rules on the entity.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution to that, as now I'm going to have the same data annotations scattered around multiple view models. If I change one, I have to remember to change them all. :/

Comment: Not necessarily. If you're not doing anything with the data that you receive from the ViewModel, there's no reason to validate again. You only need to validate if your program is going to alter the user input.

Comment: @KingIsaac - view shouldn't trust user, controller shouldn't trust view, database shouldn't trust caller. Validation on every step (even db) is good idea and it shouldn't be skipped.

Comment: @KingIsaac: Validation should be done on all layers, the data layer can be used by other assemblies, like bulk-import or a non-web frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this amazing nuget that does dynamic annotations [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) using AOP similar pattern

You could validate any logic you can dream of:

```
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Phone { get; set; }
[RequiredIf("Email != null")]
[RequiredIf("Phone != null")]
[AssertThat("AgreeToContact == true")]
public bool? AgreeToContact { get; set; }
```